# Keras model is compiled with training_v1.py instead of training.py

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, import, keras-rl

This is the minimal example to reproduce the problem:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Flatten, LeakyReLU
from keras.regularizers import l1
from rl.agents.dqn import DQNAgent

reg = l1(1e-5)
relu_alpha = 0.01

model = Sequential()

model.add(Flatten(input_shape=[128,10,20]))
model.add(Dense(16, kernel_regularizer = reg))
model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha = relu_alpha))
model.add(Dense(3, activation = "linear", kernel_regularizer = reg))

model.compile(loss='mse', jit_compile=True)
```

The result is the following error:

```
  File "C:\Users\lbosc\anaconda3\envs\ml_env3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training_v1.py", line 306, in compile
    raise TypeError(
TypeError: Invalid keyword argument(s) in `compile`: {'jit_compile'}
```

I was able to understand that the problem is with the line `import DQNAgent` which re-defines the `compile` method of `Sequential` with its own. In fact, if you delete that `import` the compilation finishes correctly.
The compile method of `keras.models.Sequential` is defined in the file `training.py` of the library and accepts the parameter `jit_compile`, while the `compile` method used by `rl.agents.dqn.DQNAgent` at the end calls the `compile` method of keras defined in the file `training_v1.py`, which is a bit different and does not accept the parameter `jit_compile`.

So, since in the successive part of the code I need the `DQNAgent`, the question at the end is: how do I force keras-rl2 to use `training.py` instead of `training_v1.py`? Or, in alternative, how do I say to my code which is the `compile` method to use?

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting the solution I finally found, even if I did not fully understand why it works. The `__init__` file in `rl.agents` imports `rl.agents.ddpg`; there you should replace the following call:

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()
```

with:

```
from tensorflow.python.framework.ops import disable_eager_execution
disable_eager_execution()
```

and there you are: keras-rl starts using the v2 functions of tensorflow instead of the v1 compatibility ones and the rest of my code, which is compatible with v2, does not find conflicts anymore.